# Hit multiple REST endpoints with single call

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

Lets say there are three endpoints

- GET /v1/customer
- GET /v1/order
- GET /v1/item

Is there any way to hit all these 3 apis with single call and get combined response in Java?

I read that Google provides this functionality in their APIs with a single endpoint in which the requests can be specified in the body and that service will spilt & process each request individually and send back combined response.

Is there any other way, that this can be achieved in rest client side? Curious!

NOTE: I'm just the consumer of the endpoint. I'm not exposing the APIs. Hence I would like to know if that is possible from rest client side

Answer (score 0):

You could at least create another endpoint that will combine results of some other endpoints.

Comment: I'm just the consumer of the endpoint. I'm not exposing the APIs. Hence I would like to know if that is possible from rest client side.

Comment: Nope. HTTP calls are passed to the specific single endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

build a new endpoints call the three endpoints?

Comment: I'm just the consumer of the endpoint. I'm not exposing the APIs. Hence I would like to know if that is possible from rest client side